# GCM is slow when pushing to iOS devices

Tags: android, ios, google-cloud-messaging

I am having issues with using GCM for iOS. Whenever I send push notifications to an Android device, I receive the notification within .5 seconds without any issues. Whenever I change the registration token to that of an iOS device(not the APN registration id), the web request takes at least 4 seconds to receive the response; and has taken up to 30 seconds to receive the push on the iOS device. Any ideas as to why this is happening or is this the type of behavior I should expect from GCM?

sample payload:

```
{
 "notification": {
   "body": "HEY"
 },
 "registration_ids": [<registration token of ios device>],
 "time_to_live": 400
}
```

The Authorization and Content-Type headers are being set as well.

Is there anything else that I need to provide to make debugging this question any easier?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Set the "priority"="high" in your payload and you should see your delivery to iOS arrive faster.

```
{
 "notification": {
   "body": "HEY"
 },
 "priority":"high",
 "registration_ids": [<registration token of ios device>],
 "time_to_live": 400
}
```